# Is the MS-Access Navigation Pane visible?

Tags: ms-access, vba

The following code to close the Access Navigation Pane works.

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

But the problem is that if the Navigation Pane is already closed then the acCmdWindowHide will just hide any other object (i.e. form, table) which was open.
I use DoCmd.TransferDatabase in my code and when this is executed the Navigation Pane is sometimes opened. This may happen if a warning message about data import appears and the user clicks cancel. To be sure the user does not see the pane I want to hide it but if it is already hidden then there is nothing to hide but the above command just hides my form and that is not what I want.

The line

```
DoCmd.NavigateTo "acNavigationCategoryObjectType"
```

is always executed and does not return anything. It does not return an error if there is no Navigation Pane to navigate to.

My question is: How can I determine if the Navigation Pane is currently open so that I know I have to close it.
Or how can I make sure that I close the Navigation Pane but no other object if I use the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This forum thread](https://access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=187697) suggests:

```
Public Function HideIt()

    ' Employee is just any existing table
    DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, "Employee", True
    If Application.CurrentObjectName = "Employee" Then DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But there is one exception: If any filter is used to show only some objects in the navigation pane and this filter does not allow the CurrentObjectName then the above code does not work because the object with that name can never be selected.  Sample: A filter "Customer" is used to show only objects with a name like Customer. If then above code tries to select Employee that can't be selected even if the navigation pane is open because the filter won't allow it. And this filter does not go away after hiding the navigation pane.  No problem in my case.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I determine if the Navigation Pane is currently open so that
> I know I have to close it. Or how can I make sure that I close the
> Navigation Pane but no other object if I use the above code?

By holding the `Application.CurrentObjectName` value before setting focus to the Nav Pane,
and then comparing that value to `Application.CurrentObjectName` after `DoCmd.NavigateTo ("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")`, you can tell if the Nav Pane can be closed.

I found that the code suggested in other examples would fail if a search filter was currently set in the navigation pane.  In some cases this would cause the active form to close.  That can lead to a bad user experience.  This routine should get around that.  I have only found two limitations:

1. The Nav Pane is open but no other objects are open.  I can't think of a good reason why you'd be hiding the Nav Pane in this instance.
2. You open tblEmployee from the Nav Pane and it becomes the active object, then you run this routine to hide the Nav Pane.  It won't do anything because tblEmployee is the active object name and it is also the selected item in the Nav Pane.  I don't think you'll run into this situation much but [YMMV](https://www.google.com/search?q=YMMV).

In either of those cases the sub will not hide the navigation pane which is better than close the active form.

```vb
Public Sub HideNavPane()
' This will hide the Navigation Pane.
' It works even if a search filter is set, unlike other solutions that may
' inadvertently close the active object.
' Limitations:  An object (form, report, query, etc) must be open and it 
'               cannot be the same name as the selected item in the nav pane
'               or this will do nothing.
  
    Dim strCurrentObjectName As String
    
    strCurrentObjectName = Application.CurrentObjectName
      
    ' Move focus to the navigation pane/database container
    DoCmd.NavigateTo ("acNavigationCategoryObjectType")
  
    If strCurrentObjectName <> Application.CurrentObjectName Then
        ' The Navigation Pane is open and has focus.
        ' Use the window menu to hide the navigation pane
        DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
    End If
  
End Sub
```